# How can I tell if a paragraph I am adding to a document is going to cause a page break?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm looping through a google sheet and creating a google doc from it.

So far so good, the text is coming across. However - I'd like there to be a way to test if a paragraph I'm going to add is going to cause a page break. I want to keep the paragraph I'm appending all on one page.  (IE - if the paragraph I'm going to add is going to cause a page break, then add a page break and then dd the paragraph)

I don't want to have to create a page break after each iteration of the loop to keep it all on one page. Any ideas?

```
body.clear();
var values = result.values;
for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
    // Insert text at the end of the document.
    if (values[i][3] != 'N') {
        body.appendParagraph(values[i][0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a partial solution that suffers from severe limitations and may not be applicable to your case, especially since you get your paragraphs programmatically.

A bird's eye view of the process is as follows:

1. Calculate the height of your document page.
2. Calculate the height of the paragraph you wish to append.
3. Call **body.appendParagraph(paragraph)** and subtract paragraph height from the page height. Keep repeating until **pageHeight < paragraphHeight**.
4. Insert a page break, reset the value of **pageHeight**.

Step 1 is the easiest. Just subtract top and bottom margins from the height value of your page to calculate the amount of space available.

```
var marginTop = body.getMarginTop();
var marginBottom = body.getMarginBottom();
var pageHeight =  body.getPageHeight() - marginTop - marginBottom;
```

Step 2 - here comes the pain. Google doesn't expose any methods for you to be able to calculate paragraph height. So my idea was to count the number of individual lines and approximate the height using the formula

```
height = numberOfLines * (fontSize + lineSpacing);
```

However, this formula is highly inaccurate - it overestimates the height, due to differences in unit measurements. As a result, I set the pageHeight to:

```
  pageHeight -= templateHeight;
```

Note that if you try to get the styles for a paragraph by calling **paragraph.getAttributes()**, all properties of the resulting object will be 'NULL', unless you set them explicitly like this:

```
 var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 11;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 0.5;
  paragraph.setAttributes(style);
```

Which brings us to the potential deal-breaker - there doesn't seem to be a way to calculate the number of individual lines, no matter what your approach is.
Please see the comments here [Counting the number of lines in Google Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409480/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-google-document?noredirect=1#comment85824618_49409480)

So, currently, there's no other solution to this issue than making sure that all your paragraphs have the same number of lines. 
If you go ahead with this assumption, steps 3 and 4 are easy.

In the code below, I use the paragraph from 'doc' as a template and paste it into the target document. Everything works as expected, but the limitation described above is likely to render the solution useless for your case unless you find a workaround.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById("YOUR_ID");
var targetBody = targetDoc.getBody();

//explicitly set styles for the template paragraph
  var template = body.getParagraphs()[0];         
  var numLines = 11; //hard-coded value
  var fontSize = 11;
  var lineSpacing = 0.5;
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = fontSize;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = lineSpacing;

  template.setAttributes(style);

var marginTop = body.getMarginTop();
var marginBottom = body.getMarginBottom();
var pageHeight =  body.getPageHeight() - marginTop - marginBottom;

  var templateHeight = numLines*(fontSize + numLines);
  pageHeight -= templateHeight;

  var pageSpaceLeft = pageHeight;

  for (var i=0; i < 20; i++) {

  var newPar = template.copy();

    if (pageSpaceLeft < templateHeight) { 
      targetBody.appendPageBreak(); 
      pageSpaceLeft = pageHeight;
    }

  pageSpaceLeft -= templateHeight;
  targetBody.appendParagraph(newPar);

  }
```