# Google Scripts: JPG to Text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

So I am trying to convert some images into text. I know in Google Drive you can just open up a jpg with google docs and it will automatically convert it, but I'm trying to convert multiple files at the same time (into one document or multiple, does not matter to me).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function doGet(request) {

 if (request.parameters.url != undefined && request.parameters.url != "") {

var imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request.parameters.url).getBlob();

var resource = {
      title: imageBlob.getName(),`enter code here`
      mimeType: imageBlob.getContentType()
    };

    var options = {
      ocr: true
    };

    var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, imageBlob, options);

    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.id);

    var text = doc.getBody().getText().replace("\n", "");

    Drive.Files.remove(docFile.id);

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(text);

  }

  else {

    return ContentService.createTextOutput("request error");

  }

}
```

The only thing is, I cannot use Google Drive API for my workplace and I'm not sure how I would go about doing this without it. I was wondering if any of you have a solution to that or any experience with this (creating a new document on your google drive for the image that you open up).

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot understand about ``I cannot use Google Drive API for my workplace``. It seems that in your script, you use it. You want to achieve what you want without using your current script?

Comment: Exactly, I wrote the script for it but at the end, I realized that they do not let us have the permissions for API. I have however requested it but yes; I want to achieve the same results as this code without the use of an API. Thanks!

Comment: In your situation, you cannot use all APIs of Google. If my understanding is correct, I think that it is required to convert to text data using OCR of outer APIs. For example, https://ocr.space/ocrapi After the image was converted to text, you can create the document using it.

Comment: Great point, thank you!

Comment: If you need, I think that I can prepare the sample script.

Comment: That would be awesome and much appreciated if you could.

Comment: You can see the sample script using the OCR at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409480/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-google-document/49827828#49827828

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Everything is now working but I still have a minor issue;

Comment: All the files that I am running OCR are being created in a google doc and these docs are all in my google drive (in an unorganized manner). I'm not sure how to insert these into specific folders. I believe the issue is in the "file = Drive.Files.insert(file, image, {ocr: true});" line. Are there any modifications I can make to export these files into a specific folder?

Comment: You can use the class DriveApp instead of Drive API. You can see the detail information at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app). And one of the samples is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910734/google-apps-script-how-do-i-create-a-file-in-a-folder).

Comment: Thank you for your help throughout this!