# How do I select a whole line programmatically inside a paragraph class in Google Docs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to get a whole line from a paragraph where the user has some text selected, the goal for this is to insert a line break in that specific line. Is there a way to do this? If not could you give me some advice to workaround this?

[This is an example of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLiU1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the paragraph line to select entire line till full stop.

Triple click one the paragraph line to select whole line.

Comment: I forgot to say but I need to do it programmatically, I'm using JavaScript for it

Answer (score 0):

- When you selected a text in a paragraph, you want to retrieve the whole paragraph.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you run this script, please select a text in a paragraph on the active Document. Then, run this script.

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var selection = doc.getSelection();
  var e = selection.getRangeElements();
  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i].getElement().getParent().getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      var p = e[i].getElement().getParent().asParagraph();
      Logger.log(p.getText())
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it for your situation.

#### References:

- [getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getselection)
- [getRangeElements()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range#getrangeelements)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

- When you selected a word in a paragraph, you want to retrieve a line including the word from a paragraph which can be seen at browser.

Unfortunately, in the current stage, this cannot be achieved. For example, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49409480) might help understanding about this. If the number of characters in a line can be retrieved, this might be able to be achieved. But it cannot achieve from the selected word. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer me but I think I hadn't expressed myself correctly (english isn't my main language, sorry). I've edited the post with an example of what I want to do, basically I want to select programmatically the whole line the user has selected. For example, I select a word of a line so programmatically I want to get that whole line to then add a break to that specific line.

Comment: @Jose Ojalvo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience, too. Can you explain about your added image? Because I got not to be able to understand what you want to do from the image. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: No way, my fault for not being straight forward enough. Let's say we have a paragraph like the one in the image, and what I want is that the user can select a word of that paragraph (you know, double click or whatever selection the user does), so when the user hits a button I want to through JavaScript get that specific line where the word is located to insert a break line at the end of that line. I apologise for wasting your time like that.

Comment: @Jose Ojalvo Thank you for replying. When you selected a word in a paragraph, you want to retrieve a line including the word from a paragraph which can be seen at browser. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's it! I want to know off that's even possible because I'm stuck at this point with the plug-in I'm developing

Comment: @Jose Ojalvo Thank you for replying. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? I apologize that in the current stage, your question cannot be resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I'll take a look at this and hope I can work around this, Google Apps Script is driving me crazy.

Comment: @Jose Ojalvo Thank you for replying. I apologize that I have to say that your question cannot be achieved in the current stage.